# Differentiation of Transcendent Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $f(x, y) = x^2y + e^{-xy^3}$.
By using the derivative definition: $f_x(x, y) = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x + \Delta x,y) - f(x,y)}{\Delta x}$, evaluate $f_x(1,2)$.

I am stuck after dealing $e^{\cdots}$ expression in the limit form. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
f(x + \Delta x,y) = (x + \Delta x)^2y + e^{-(x + \Delta x)y^3} =
(x + \Delta x)^2y + e^{-xy^3 }e^{-\Delta xy^3}.
$$